# Login failed for user '<mysqllogin>'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: <local machine>] issues

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, logins

Over the last 10 days or so, I've started to get 'Login failed for user ''. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: ]' entries nearly every 5 mins in my SQL 2008 logs and I can't figure out why.

I've done the trace and this is falling down on accessing the master db every time and it's allegedly coming from my IIS - but my web app (via user access) isn't connecting to it at the times stated in the log.

What I don't understand is that it's trying to use my user-created SQL login, which connects to the master DB and all of my other SQL DBs fine without problems when I do an ASP connection string and/or use SQL Enterprise Manager.

I've looked at the login's details in SQL Server Logins and although it wasn't user mapped to the master db it never has been.

Does anybody know how I can track what is calling it from within IIS?

Thanks

Tom

Comment: If you stop all the websites in IIS Manager, do the attempts stop? If they do, start sites one by one until you find the one that's the culprit.

Comment: What I can't understand is that if I run up SQL Enterprise manager, log in with SQL authentication, use the exact same username and password as always and then execute 'use master' it works fine.  Surely that is exactly the same as connecting via an ADO connection string??

Comment: Are you sure it's the master database it's failing on? Does it have permissions to all the databases on the server? I'm almost positive the error should specify the exact database on recent versions of SQL. But if it doesn't violate your security, then give it read only to whatever databases it doesn't have access to. And then once a day, or every few hours or whatever revoke access one database at a time. And see if it errors out again.